# Innvertibility of a bounded and linear operator on Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that $I+T^*T$ is boundedly invertible, where $T$ is a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space. I have shown that it's surjective and injective (i.e., a bijection). Can I now conclude that it's invertible? Or do I need to show more? Also, does boundedly invertible mean that $I+T^*T$ is bounded and invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have proved that $I+TT^{\ast}$ is bijective, then by Open Mapping Theorem it is an open map, so the inverse is bounded as well.

Comment: Does bijection mean invertible?

Comment: Yes, it is algebraic invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elmentary proof not invoking Open Mapping Theorem: $\langle (I+T^{*}T)x , x \rangle =\|x\|^{2}+\|Tx\|^{2} \geq \|x\|^{2}$. This implies that $\|x\|^{2} \leq \|(I+T^{*}T)x\| \|x\|$. But this means $\|(I+T^{*}T))^{-1}y\| \leq \|y\|$ so the inverse in fact has norm less than or equal to $1$.